# How to Find Out the Dates when Windows was Not Started

Tags: c#, windows, .net-4.5

All, I want to find out the dates that the Windows OS was not started. Is there a way to do this in C# using .NET4.5+?

Following searches on this I have found nothing and am not sure where to start with this. If this is not possible via C# is there a way to do this via the OS?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to check the event logs. Here are some of the relevant eventIDs:

```
EventID Source              Description
12      Kernel General      Operating System Start
13      Kernel General      Operating System Shutdown
1       Power-Troubleshooter    Operating System Woke up from Sleep
42      Kernel-Power        Operating System going to Hibernate/Sleep
```

By looking for eventid 12, you will be able to find out the dates when the OS was started.

More info at http://unlimit.in/calculating-uptimes-in-windows.html